# Passing a variable into a SQL request : Attempt to concatenate local 'variable' (a table value)

Tags: sqlite, lua, coronasdk

I would like to pass a variable in different functions, within an SQL request, as described below :

```
popup = display.newImage( "interface/popup-1.png")
popup.width=568
popup.height=232
popup.anchorX=0.5
popup.anchorY=0.5
popup.isVisible=false
popup.y=-700
popup:addEventListener( 'tap', displaySpeech)
popup.destination="mycharacter"
camera:add(popup,1,false)
```

> This is where i took my variable 'character'

```
function speak(event)
          character = event.target.destination      
          displaySpeech(character)
        end

    num=1
    function displaySpeech(character)
        displaySpeech_get(""..num.."",character)
        num=num+1

    end

    function displaySpeech_get(number,character)

        for row in db:nrows("SELECT * FROM speeches WHERE character='"..character.."' LIMIT "..tostring(number)..",1") do
              myMessage.text=row.speech
        end

    end
```

The first "reply" of my SQL request appareas but once i call a second time the function displaySpeech_get(number, character) it shows an error. I tried to print the variable 'character', it gets a table ID !

Any solution ?

Comment: You need to show us where you declare the character. The error is pretty simple, you aren't passing it a variable you are passing it an entire table.

Comment: Okay I understand this ! But why it works the first time ? I receive the value of my variable stored in the "destination" attribute of my object ?

Comment: I am sorry - I misread the code. I am unable to locate the cause.

Comment: I found the origin of the problem : The event.target.destination is working on the first calling, but once i call the function on the second "touch event", it shows a table like : table : 0340590B0 ... Is there any "process" or "method", i can use to save the event.target.destination is a global variable ?